# How to iterate windows in Chrome on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome

On Mac, I was always able to iterate over windows in Chrome and Safari using "command-`"

This seems to have stopped working in latest Chrome, Version 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit) with OSX, Version 10.10.2 (14C109).

I could not find keyboard shortcut settings, or anything of the like for this feature, does anyone know how to re-enable this?

I found this extension, but it does not have next/previous window: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck

It still works in Safari.

Comment: Can you check if it works when you set the key combination in system properties to something else than the default? (Have no problems with this function here but also have 41 already)

Comment: I updated Chrome, and it works again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user2543253 who mentioned that it was working on a later version of chrome, I updated Chrome, and the problem went away.

Thanks user2543253!

(Just so this does not go unanswered.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not as easy as a "command-tab" kind of switching, but you can press F10, then press the left or right arrow key, then press F10 again.